# Closed line integral, arrow direction, is this correct?

Tags: integration

I have the following closed integral (with circle through the integral sign):

$\int y^2dx + 2ydy$

and the curve is drawn as two functions: y1 = $\sqrt{x}$ and y2 = $x^2$, they intersect at (x,y) = (1,1), and the arrows are drawn: upwards on y2 and downwards on y1.

I parametrize both: x = t, y1 = $\sqrt{t}$, y2 = $t^2$ , 0 <= t <= 1

$\int_0^1 t^4dt + \int_0^1 2*t^2dt - \int_0^1 tdt - \int_0^1 2*\sqrt{t}dt$

is the parametrization correct? I'm not sure about the + and - signs though, thanks for the help !

Comment: Btw you can use \oint to get the closed line integral symbol

Answer (score 1):

Recall that after you parameterize, you want

$$\int_C y^2dx + 2ydy = \int_0^1 \left(y^2\frac{dx}{dt} + 2y\frac{dy}{dt}\right)dt$$

Now, it's easier to work with $C$ if we break it up into two paths. We can do that as follows:

Let $C_1=\alpha(t)$ be the path given by $y_1=x^2$ and $C_2=\beta(t)$ be the path given by $y_2=\sqrt{x}$. (Note that I switched $y_1$ and $y_2$, so that we're going "upwards" on $y_1$.) Then, we can parameterize each as follows:

$$\alpha(t) = t^2, \ \ \ \  t \in [0,1]$$

$$\beta(t) = \sqrt{1-t}, \ \ \ \ t \in [0,1]$$

(Why do we use $\sqrt{1-t}$?) This gives us the proper orientation. Now, remember to take derivatives when transforming coordinates. Namely,

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=1, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{dy_1}{dt} = \frac{d\alpha}{dt} = 2t, \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \frac{dy_2}{dt} = \frac{d\beta}{dt} = -\frac{1}{2}(1-t)^{-1/2}$$

Now, we have

$$\int_C y^2dx + 2ydy = \int_{C_1} y^2dx + 2ydy + \int_{C_2} y^2dx + 2ydy$$

We can now compute each individually. For example,

$$\int_{C_1} y^2dx + 2ydy = \int_0^1 ((t^2)^2 + (2t^2)(2t))dt$$

Comment: On second thought, you can indeed use $\beta(t)=\sqrt{t}$, as long as you take the negative of the integral, as you did. But both parameterizations are equivalent. Just make sure you also remember to take derivatives when transforming coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a ton!